# Dynamically load ControllerBase implementations from assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a web service using ASP.NET Core 2.1 where I need the service to be able to register BaseControllers loaded from DLL's through reflection. However I can't seem to find how to register a BaseController to the service configuration.

In `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup 
{

   ....

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
   {
        var builder = services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        /// This now loads the base controllers located 
        /// within the dll's through reflection and the
        /// BaseControllers are initialized as well
        IList<ControllerBase> controllers = PluginLoader.Instance.GetControllers();

        foreach (ControllerBase controllerBase in controllers)
        {
             /// Here I hope that I can add the controllerBase to services but 
             /// I just can't seem to find a way to do it. Is it even possible?
             /// I'm thinking that builder.AddControllersAsServices() might be useful for something but just can't seem to get it right
        }
   }
}
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Register all `Controller`s? You reference `BaseController`s, do you mean `ControllerBase`s? Registering and Instantiating are two seperate things; are you trying to use only *one* instance of *each `Controller` type*? You can register `Services` and have the framework instantiate these *per request*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's possible to add an assembly to the builder and that will make the controller(s) available. So it's achievable with a minor refactor of the loader.

Tested code:

```
if (controllers != null && controllers.Any())
{
     foreach (ControllerBase controllerBase in controllers)
     {
         builder.AddApplicationPart(controllerBase.GetType().Assembly);
     }
 }
```