# How to register new REST API endpoints after loading new dll at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Blazor Server App with NET 6 application and it has an option to load dlls with new REST API entries.

The application loads the dll and the assembly while running without any issues, except that the REST API access points are not accessible only after restarting the server.

So my question is: Is it possible to load (refresh/reload the controller service) and have access to the REST API access points without restarting the server ?

Comment: Are you using application part manager? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Liero yes, tried also to force all controllers to be added, but in that case, it is only exposing endpoints which are already there, if the user provide a new DLL with a new controller it won't be accessible unless the server is restarted (the system is designed to store those DLLs and the loading before and after restarts is done similarly, everything is loaded correctly in both case except the controllers), I tried also to have access to the controller service to force refresh but I didn't succeed

Comment: @Liero this was my first direction but it is not working on runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659164/5733399

Comment: I think the routes are not being registered. I would google that.